# Can I add operators to existing classes?

Tags: equals, equality, kotlin

In Kotlin, I would like to add an `equals` method to an existing class that hasn't got an `equals` implementation yet.

In my case I would like to compare two `BooleanArray` instances. `equals` (and thus `==`) should return `true` for two arrays `a1` and `a2` if they are of the same size and if all items are equal. Thus `a1[i] === a2[i]` for all `0 <= i < size`.

[The documentation states that operators can be defined by extension methods](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html):

> The function must be declared as
>
> `fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean`
>
> Or an extension function with the same parameter list and return type.

`BooleanArray` doesn't provide an `equals` method.

So I wrote:

```
fun BooleanArray.equals(other: Any?): Boolean { return ... }
```

However this extension gets ignored. When I compare two `BooleanArray`s such as

```
BooleanArray(0).equals(BooleanArray(0))
```

it doesn't call the extension method and thus always evaluates to `false` for two different instances.

Comment: I confirm the behavior. I think that's a bug. They are messing with that part of the compiler a lot these days

Comment: Please report it to the bug tracker http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT

Comment: Thanks for counter checking. Filed here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10055

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is outdated and this is no longer possible. If you declare your `equals` extension with that signature, it will never be invoked because [member functions always win](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extensions-are-resolved-statically) over extensions, and there is a member function `equals` in `Any`. The only way you can provide your own `equals` is by overriding that member function from `Any`, but that is of course not possible for arrays. I suggest you try using lists or other data structures with well-defined `equals` / `hashCode` behavior rather than arrays.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Although `BooleanArray` was convient to use, I will switch to `List<Boolean>` now. As Kotlin has reach 1.0 beta status it could be a good time to update the official documentation that I cited.